# Extract date from a web page using Python from its HTML

Tags: python, html, date, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the date from the following webpage
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/blog/2024/01/29/join-us-at-infosec-jupyterthon-2024/
Used the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Function to get datetime from a webpage
def get_datetime_from_url(url):
    try:
       response = requests.get(url, timeout=10)  # Added timeout parameter
    response.raise_for_status()

    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        datetime_element = soup.find('time', {'datetime': True})
        if datetime_element:
            return datetime_element['datetime']
        else:
            post_datetime = soup.find(class_='post-datetime')
            if post_datetime:
                return post_datetime.text.strip()

        # If date not found in HTML, check meta tags
        meta_tags = soup.find_all('meta', attrs={'itemprop': 'datePublished'}) + \
                    soup.find_all('meta', attrs={'property': 'article:published_time'}) + \
                    soup.find_all('meta', attrs={'property': 'og:date_created'})

        for tag in meta_tags:
            if 'content' in tag.attrs:
                return tag['content']

        # New part to extract date using various classes and tags
        date_classes = ["single__date font-weight-bold d-block small text-neutral-600"]

        for class_name in date_classes:
            date_element = soup.find(class_=class_name)
            if date_element:
                return date_element.get_text(strip=True)
except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, AttributeError, TimeoutError):
    pass
except AssertionError:
    print("AssertionError occurred. Ignoring.")

return None

# Hyperlink to scrape
 hyperlink = 'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/blog/2024/01/29/join-us-at-infosec- 
   jupyterthon-2024/'

# Lists to store URL, Hyperlinks, and datetime values
url_list = []
hyperlinks_list = []
datetime_list = []

# Extract datetime value for the specified hyperlink
try:
    datetime_value = get_datetime_from_url(hyperlink)
    if datetime_value:
        url_list.append("Specify the URL here")  # Specify the URL corresponding to the provided hyperlink
    hyperlinks_list.append(hyperlink)
    datetime_list.append(datetime_value)
    print("Datetime value fetched.")
else:
    print("Datetime value not found.")
except TimeoutError:
    print("Timeout while fetching datetime value.")
except AssertionError:
    print("AssertionError occurred.")

# Create a DataFrame from the collected data
data = {"URL": url_list, "Hyperlinks": hyperlinks_list, "Datetime": datetime_list}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)
```

The HTML structure [image]

Not sure where am I going wrong. But it would be great if someone can help. Also tried using the htmldate Python module. This is a webscrapping exercide wherein I would need the date of  publication.

Comment: Did you read the response.text ? It says `Your current User-Agent string appears to be from an automated process, if this is incorrect, please click this link`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added headers to mimic a request from Google Chrome on a Windows machine.
Change **response.text** to **response.content** to parse the full page in HTML form.

```
def get_datetime_from_url(url):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        datetime_element = soup.find('time', {'datetime': True})
        if datetime_element:
            return datetime_element['datetime']
```

[image]